# how to include jquery from node_modules in angular1

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Here this is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><% include ./header %>
<link type="text/javascript" src="loginScript" ></head>
<body class='home-page' ng-app="loginApp" ng-controller="LoginCtrl"> </body></html>
```

**header.ejs**
     My application

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"> 
 </script>
```

**server.js**

```
      var express = require('express');
      var app = express();
      var mysql = require('mysql');
      var path = require('path');
      var http = require('http');
      var fs = require('fs');
      var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
      app.set('view engine','ejs');

      app.get('/',(req,res) =>{
         res.render('./login_page');
      });
      app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
      var server = http.createServer();
      app.listen(8081);
```

While running node `server.js` the following error is displayed:
    localhost/:12 GET 
    http://localhost:8081/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js 404 (Not Found)

```
localhost/:1 Refused to execute script from 
'http://localhost:8081/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js' because 
its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type 
checking is enabled.
```

I have `node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js` but i don't know why i am getting this error.

Comment: Did you have a typo and ... `header.ejs` is actually `header.js` or not?

Comment: no its header.ejs file only.

Comment: share `server.js` code too

Comment: okay i will update

Comment: @VilasKumkar updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

I solved this issue,I am declared static path route in server.js so that is my static path,
so I have to call the file from that path like (../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js)

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"> 
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually triying to serve a static resource, so you have to enable a path where locate your static files like scripts, css, images, etc

If you are using Expressjs for the backend, check this link out http://expressjs.com/es/starter/static-files.html

Comment: yeah I am already added that one...now I updated my server.js code too

Comment: Actually you want to serve jquery.min.js from that path, /static/js/jquery.min.js for example, not ../node_modules/... etc